# How to iterate over over all Unicode characters?

Tags: javascript, unicode, iteration

Is it possible to iterate over all Unicode characters (UTF-8)? Thanks!
I've tried using:

```
character = String.fromCharCode(i);
```

But I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Put that into a `for` loop that iterates over all the possible values of `i`.

Comment: So for the charcode, what format is that? something like x\00000?

Comment: That would be the format for writing it as a literal string. But you don't need to do that, `fromCharCode()` returns the character.

Comment: easier said than done @Barmar, I came looking exactly for the limits of the possible values and the format (decimal, hex, whatever) to iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [to the docs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.3.2), the parameter passed to `String.fromCharCode(a)` is converted calling [`ToUint16`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.7) and then said character is returned. You may call it with any number you want but the values will be capped to between 0 and 2<sup>16</sup> or 2<sup>32</sup>

```
highNumber = 500; //This could go very high
out = ""
for(i=0;i<highNumber;i++){
    out += String.fromCharCode(i);
}
console.log(out);
```

**Danger note** if you run this code using `2^16`you may freeze your tab or browser, it's way too big. This is understanding you want to iterate over **all characters** and not **all characters in a *given string*** which is quite a different thing.

A sample output of a more reasonable `highNumber`(ie 500) is the following:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqr
stuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæç
èéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺ
ĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſƀƁƂƃƄƅƆƇƈƉƊƋƌƍ
ƎƏƐƑƒƓƔƕƖƗƘƙƚƛƜƝƞƟƠơƢƣƤƥƦƧƨƩƪƫƬƭƮƯưƱƲƳƴƵƶƷƸƹƺƻƼƽƾƿǀǁǂǃǄǅǆǇǈǉǊǋǌǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǝǞǟǠ
ǡǢǣǤǥǦǧǨǩǪǫǬǭǮǯǰǱǲǳ
```

Comment: Just an observation, the question was only about the _iteration_, it's not necessary about building a new string that comprises of all possible characters. For example, I came here looking for max limit of charcode values. I plan to loop through and compare only. Memory issues should not apply then.

Answer (score 11):

UTF-8 is an encoding! JavaScript strings are [(mostly)](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding) encoded in UTF-16. Encoding is only important if you’re working in an environment that doesn’t support ES6’s [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint). Getting a string from a codepoint with ES6:

```
var s = String.fromCodePoint(codePoint);
```

and without ES6, using a UTF-16 [surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) for characters U+10000 and onwards:

```
var s;

if (codePoint < 0x10000) {
    s = String.fromCharCode(codePoint);
} else {
    var offset = codePoint - 0x10000;
    s = String.fromCharCode(0xd800 + (offset >> 10),
                            0xdc00 + (offset & 0x3ff));
}
```

Codepoints range from U+0000 to U+10FFFF (1 114 112 values), but not everything that range is a valid Unicode character. You can get a table from http://www.unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt and extract the characters you really want to iterate over.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to iterate character by character over a string that may contain UTF-8 multi-codepoint characters (i.e. emojis or non-latin alphabets) is `Array.from()`:

```js
const bugs = ''

// WRONG, does not account for characters with > 2 Unicode code points
bugs.split('')
// Array(6) [ "\ud83d", "\udc1b", "\ud83d", "\udc1b", "\ud83d", "\udc1b" ]

// CORRECT
Array.from(bugs)
// Array(3) [ "", "", "" ]
```

Then, iterate as you may iterate any normal array (suggested: `map`/`forEach`).

More information: https://medium.com/@giltayar/iterating-over-emoji-characters-the-es6-way-f06e4589516

Comment: Definitely `Array.from` is the correct answer!

Comment: You can also use `[...bugs]`

Answer (score 2):

I think this might define what to iterate over exactly:

[image]

Comment: sorry for downvoting, this is technically correct but way too low-level!

Comment: just because someone else thinks it's too low level, doesn't mean some of us appreciate that chart...  it's great to know the ranges and what better form than a chart... upvoted...  I would rather have both, simple answers and complex answers.  Then people have a choice on which level they want to implement.

Answer (score -4):

A Javascript string has a length property.  You can iterate over the characters simply:

```
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var char = str[i],
       code = str.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. This code iterates over 16-bit "chars", even when 2 of them constitute a surrogate pair and thus represent one character. Try `''.length` as example.